# Is it possible to layout this HTML table + customized dendrogram using MATLAB's publish command?

Tags: html, matlab, visualization, matlab-figure, dendrogram

I would like to put together a more publication-worthy (and more easily produced) version of the diagram that I've hacked together below:

[image: hacked together diagram]

Basically, it's a two part illustration with an HTML table on the left (showing different cluster assignments from varying parameters) and a modified *dengrogram* plot on the right.

I'm guessing it's apparent from the snapshot what I'm trying to add to the plot… Basically it could be a set of horizontal, stacked bars that show how the different parameters grouped the observations into different clusters. I used brackets with the cluster numbers when drawing these by hand, but anything that underlines the right observation numbers would be acceptable.

I realize there are two parts to this question: How to get the two-up layout when one of the panels is HTML instead of a figure, and how to modify the plot. [If only one part gets answered here, I can ask for the other in a separate question.]

Answer (score 1):

You can label your plot using `line` and `text`.  You need to set the `clipping` property to `off` in order for lines to show up outside of your axes.  Here's an example:

```
data = [1,3,4,5; 2,6,7,8; 9,3,7,4;3,8,5,2];
tree = linkage(data,'average');
figure()
dendrogram(tree)
set(gca,'Position',[0.13, 0.3,0.775, 0.65])

h1 = line([1,1],[4,4.8],'Color','k');
h2 = line([1,3],[4,4],'Color','k');
h3 = line([3,3],[4,4.8],'Color','k');
set(h1,'Clipping','off')
set(h2,'Clipping','off')
set(h3,'Clipping','off')

ht = text(1.7,3.9,'Label');
```

Comment: Where is a good place to start learning more about customizing figures like this in MATLAB?